# Determining if my password hashing method is safe

Tags: php, hash

I've been reading through and I'm a bit confused about storing passwords and how people can crack them. The safest way seems to be a very confusing topic for me. I started using md5 and after reading how outdated it is I started using the php_hash function like so

```
$hash = password_hash($plainTextPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

I've been told to hash it again using salt and I understand how to do it. My question is why would one need to rehash their password? Most people just copy the code and use it not knowing why it's appropriate but for future purposes I'd like to know how do you know if the method you use for hashing your password is "hackable"?

Comment: Who told you to hash it again and using salt? [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) creates its own salt. Re-hashing will only cause trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've been told to hash it again using salt…

**What you have been told is wrong**. Ignore whoever told you that.

The PHP `password_hash()` API is not a plain hash function; it already performs all the appropriate steps for hashing a password itself, including adding a salt. Don't add anything to it; just use it as-is.

Comment: Thanks alot. This saves me alot of time